# How to embed json in a command line called in a ruby script?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I'm trying to run the following command (which works) inside a ruby script

```
knife bootstrap windows winrm 'mynode' -N 'mynode' -x 'Administrator' -P 'password' -p 5985 -j '{"db-mssql" : {"full_install" : true, "cluster_install" : true}}'
```

I've attempted this...

```
cmd=%Q{knife bootstrap windows winrm 'mynode' -N 'mynode' \
         -x 'Administrator' -P 'password' -p 5985 \
         "echo '{\\"db-mssql\\" : { \\"full_install\\" : true, \\"cluster_install\\" : false}}' | -j /dev/stdin"}
puts (cmd)
system(cmd)
```

...and this...

```
cmd=%Q{knife bootstrap windows winrm 'mynode' -N 'mynode' \
         -x 'Administrator' -P 'password' -p 5985 \
         -j '{\\"db-mssql\\" : { \\"full_install\\" : true, \\"cluster_install\\" : false}}'}
puts (cmd)
system(cmd)
```

...resulting in a JSON Parse error by the interpreter. What is the correct syntax?

Comment: Why are you using two backslashes instead of one?

Comment: Just stop escaping things which do not have to be escaped. you're using `%Q{}` which allows you to not escape double quotes. `cmd=%Q{knife bootstrap windows winrm 'mynode' -N 'mynode' -x 'Administrator' -P 'password' -p 5985 -j '{"db-mssql" : {"full_install" : true, "cluster_install" : true}}'}
` should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a ruby hash and then call .to_json on it.

Make sure to 'require json' in order to get the .to_json functionality.

Comment: I like this answer best. I had to put require "json" in my file so the Hash object inherits the .to_json function.